# Introducing KoTHComm: A framework for your King of the Hill challenges

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

I'd like to introduce [KoTHComm](https://github.com/nathanmerrill/KoTHComm).  I've been working on this for many months now, and I feel like its at a (somewhat) stable point.

KoTHComm is a modular framework built to help write King of the Hill challenges faster.  It provides:

- A communication system to **communicate with other languages**
- A downloader to automatically **download the latest submissions** from the site
- A tournament system, which allows you to **organize players into games** in a variety of ways
- A scoring system, which allows you to **combine game scores** in smart ways
- A map module, providing many types of **extensible maps and map generation**
- **GUI components** to easily show the current state of the game

It works too:  I used it on my past KoTH, [Stock Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/91566/stock-exchange-koth), and I will be using it on my [upcoming KoTH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/99744/battle-of-the-fellowships-koth).  **All features are optional**, and I've tried to limit the dependencies between the different parts.

I would like to note that the framework is still under heavy development, and I cannot guarantee backwards compatibility of any kind.  I'm sure it has bugs, but I try to fix them as fast as possible.

FAQ:

- What language is it written in?

  - Java 8.  Yes, you must write your controller in Java.  If you hate Java, tough luck.  Submissions *don't* have to be written in Java, but I'd highly recommend limiting them to Java for speed purposes
- What do you plan on doing?

  - Store scores in a persistent database (which means that you can start your controller multiple times, and save all of your scores)
  - Hosting KoTHs on a website.  This will not be an automatic process, and I will pick and choose which ones I will host.  I'd also love to get a stack snippet to work with it as well
  - Add tests and comments for all of my code
  - Flesh out map generation
- Do you want help?

  - Sure!  Either send a pull request, or talk to me [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)
- Do you plan on porting this to other languages?

  - No.

If you have any questions or feedback, post it below.  If you have any bugs, post a bug report on Github.

Comment: Congrats on "releasing" this! Thanks for your excellent contribution to the community!

Comment: But Java will make the controllers so much *longer*...

Comment: I'm confused. By longer, do you mean the size of the jar? That's true for any library

Comment: @NathanMerrill No, mbomb means code size because we all hate Java a lot.

Comment: (also, you should copy this into the repo's readme because not having a readme in the repo is mildly baffling)

Comment: I've been wanting to add a readme, but I want more "how to use" instructions

Comment: @NathanMerrill I believe mbomb007's comment was a joke in reference to golf, not an actual criticism :)

Comment: Oh I figured that out :)

Comment: How about linking to this from the KotH tag wiki?